# Kubernetes node NotReady perhaps due to invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference in reconciler.go

Tags: kubernetes

My experimental, two-node Kubernetes 1.13.2 unfortunately entered a mode where the second node is `NotReady`. I've tried `systemctl restart kubelet` on both nodes, but this has not helped so far.

`journalctl -u kubelet.service` on the master node ends with this line:

```
reconciler.go:154] Reconciler: start to sync state
```

`journalctl -u kubectl.service` on the second node contains these lines:

```
server.go:999] Started kubelet
kubelet.go:1308] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data in memory cache
kubelet.go:1412] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
fs_resource_analyzer.go:66] Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer
status_manager.go:148] Kubernetes client is nil, not starting status manager.
kubelet.go:1829] Starting kubelet main sync loop.
kubelet.go:1846] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful]
server.go:137] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
server.go:333] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
volume_manager.go:248] Starting Kubelet Volume Manager
desired_state_of_world_populator.go:130] Desired state populator starts to run
container.go:409] Failed to create summary reader for "/system.slice/atop.service": none of the resources are being tracked.
kubelet.go:1846] skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet]
kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
cpu_manager.go:155] [cpumanager] starting with none policy
cpu_manager.go:156] [cpumanager] reconciling every 10s
policy_none.go:42] [cpumanager] none policy: Start
kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
reconciler.go:154] Reconciler: start to sync state
runtime.go:69] Observed a panic: "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" (runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:76
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:65
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/runtime/runtime.go:51
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:522
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:513
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:82
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:390
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:562
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:599
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:419
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:330
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:155
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:134
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:88
/workspace/anago-v1.13.2-beta.0.75+cff46ab41ff0bb/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/_output/dockerized/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/volumemanager/reconciler/reconciler.go:143
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
kubelet_node_status.go:278] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
...
```

What's going on here and how can I remedy this situation?

**UPDATE** I've now stopped `kubelet.service` on both nodes and then removed all docker containers (`docker rm`) and images (`docker rmi`) also on both nodes. I've then restarted `kubelet.service` on the master only. Kubernetes apparently pulls in all of its own images and starts them again, but now see multiple connection refused errors in `journalctl -u kubelet.service`, such as:

```
kubelet_node_status.go:94] Unable to register node "my_node" with API server: Post https://my_master:6443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp my_master:6443: connect: connection refused
```

`kubectl get nodes` can still access the API server normally. So perhaps this closer to the root cause of what I am facing. Is it correct to assume that at this point the kubelet is trying to connect to the API server? How can I check whether the relevant credentials are still intact?

Comment: Report that issue in [Kubernetes issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues), it looks as a bug.

Comment: try to check the docker (if you are using int) status in your server, try to prune unused images and make sure is working fine.

Comment: @Andres08P This did not solve the issue but revealed more about what may be the root cause. Have updated the Q accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue remained unexplained and I had to recreate the cluster with `kubeadm reset`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is kinda hard to troubleshoot without seeing the whole configuration.

however try to follow this check list.

- make sure the kubeconfig is well set up.
- do you have enabled all services in master and worker? node systemctl enable {component}
- check you have the right public IP in your kubelet.service pointing to your api-server (this seems to be the error regarding to the last comment) or check it in your, unless you have in the same machine (localhost)
- check these links that have been useful for me at the time to boopstrap a k8s cluster. https://medium.com/containerum/4-ways-to-bootstrap-a-kubernetes-cluster-de0d5150a1e4 and https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/09-bootstrapping-kubernetes-workers.md

Comment: FWIK almost all components run as docker containers, so which ones would you "systemctl enable" exactly?

Comment: if you are running all components as docker containers, you do not have to enable anything except for kubelet .  however and just to discard try applying 

```- systemctl enable kubelet
- systemctl restart kubelet```

then and as my last call:  if you are running all components as a docker, make sure first, you are effectively running api-server with https, also that you have exposed the port 6443 so you can connect with the api server. 

according to this error:https://my_master:6443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp my_master:6443: connect: connection refused, this is purely connectivity error.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple: I did all of this before. I'll try `kubeadm reset` next.